# Pair items of a list depending on value

Tags: python, xml, list, tuples

I have an xml file like the following:

```
<edge from="0/0" to="0/1" speed="10"/>
<edge from="0/0" to="1/0" speed="10"/>
<edge from="0/1" to="0/0" speed="10"/>
<edge from="0/1" to="0/2" speed="10"/>
...
```

Note, that there exist pairs of from-to and vice versa. (In the example above only the pair `("0/0","0/1")` and `("0/1","0/0")` is visible, however there is a partner for every entry.) Also, note that those pairs are not ordered.

The file describes edges within a [SUMO](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Networks/SUMO_Road_Networks#Normal_Edges) network simulation. I want to assign new speeds randomly to the different streets. However, every `<edge>` entry only describes one direction(lane) of a street. Hence, I need to find its "partner".

The following code distributes the speed values lane-wise only:

```
import xml.dom.minidom as dom
import random
edgexml = dom.parse("plain.edg.xml")
MAX_SPEED_OPTIONS = ["8","9","10"]
for edge in edgexml.getElementsByTagName("edge"):
    x = random.randint(0,2)
    edge.setAttribute("speed", MAX_SPEED_OPTIONS[x])
```

Is there a simple (pythonic) way to maybe gather those pairs in tuples and then assign the same value to both?

If you know a better way to solve my problem using SUMO tools, I'd be happy too. However I'm still interested in how I can solve the given abstract list problem in python as it is not just a simple zip like in related questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can walk the list of edges and nest another iteration over all edges to search for possible partners. Since this is of quadratic complexity, we can even reduce calculation time by only walking over not yet visited edges in the nested run.

### Solution

(for a detailed description, scroll down)

```
import xml.dom.minidom as dom
import random

edgexml = dom.parse('sampledata/tmp.xml')
MSO = [8, 9, 10]

edge_groups = []
passed = []
for idx, edge in enumerate(edgexml.getElementsByTagName('edge')):
    if edge in passed:
        continue

    partners = []
    for partner in edgexml.getElementsByTagName('edge')[idx:]:
        if partner.getAttribute('from') == edge.getAttribute('to') \
        and partner.getAttribute('to') == edge.getAttribute('from'):
            partners.append(partner)

    edge_groups.append([edge] + partners)
    passed.extend([edge] + partners)

for e in edge_groups:
    print('NEW EDGE GROUP')
    x = random.choice(MSO)
    for p in e:
        p.setAttribute('speed', x)
        print('  E from "%s" to "%s" at "%s"' % (p.getAttribute('from'), p.getAttribute('to'), x))
```

Yields the output:

```
NEW EDGE GROUP
  E from "0/0" to "0/1" at "8"
  E from "0/1" to "0/0" at "8"
NEW EDGE GROUP
  E from "0/0" to "1/0" at "10"
NEW EDGE GROUP
  E from "0/1" to "0/2" at "9"
```

### Detailed description

```
edge_groups = []
passed = []
```

Initialize the result structure `edge_groups`, which will be a list of lists holding *partnered* edges in groups. The additional list `passed` will help us to avoid redundant edges in our result.

```
for idx, edge in enumerate(edgexml.getElementsByTagName('edge')):
```

Start iterating over the list of all edges. I use `enumerate` here to obtain the index at the same time, because our nested iteration will only iterate over a sub-list starting at the current index to reduce complexity.

```
    if edge in passed:
        continue
```

Stop, if we have visited this edge at any point in time before. This does only happen if the edge has been recognized as a partner of another list before (due to index-based sublisting). If it has been taken as the partner of another list, we can omit it with no doubt.

```
    partners = []
    for partner in edgexml.getElementsByTagName('edge')[idx:]:
        if partner.getAttribute('from') == edge.getAttribute('to') \
        and partner.getAttribute('to') == edge.getAttribute('from'):
            partners.append(partner)
```

Initialize helper list to store identified partner edges. Then, walk through all edges in the **remaining list** starting from the current index. I.e. do not iterate over edges that have already been passed in the outer iteration. If the potential partner is an actual partner (from/to matches), then append it to our `partners` list.

```
    edge_groups.append([edge] + partners)
    passed.extend([edge] + partners)
```

The nested iteration has passed and `partners` holds all identified partners for the current `edge`. Push them into one list and append it to the result variable `edge_groups`. Since it is unneccessarily complex to check against the 2-level list `edge_groups` to see whether we have already traversed an edge in the next run, we will additionally keep a list of already used nodes and call it `passed`.

```
for e in edge_groups:
    print('NEW EDGE GROUP')
    x = random.choice(MSO)
    for p in e:
        p.setAttribute('speed', x)
        print('  E from "%s" to "%s" at "%s"' % (p.getAttribute('from'), p.getAttribute('to'), x))
```

Finally, we walk over all groups of edges in our result `edge_groups`, randomly draw a speed from `MSO` (hint: use `random.choice()` to randomly choose from a list), and assign it to all edges in this group.

Comment: What a GREAT answer! Thank you very much for your detailed explanation! On top of that you were even extremely fast. I like how you are trying to reduce complexity.
Note: since there is only one possible partner I am not using a `partners` list.